# How to get Sublime Text 3 to automatically highlight CSHTML as HTML

Tags: html, sublime-text-3, syntax-highlighting

I have a bunch of .CSHTML files that I want to be highlighted. Every time I open a .CSHTML file I have to go to the bottom right of the sublime text window and manually tell it to treat the CSHTML as HTML. How do I force SB3 to automatically do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can install the [HTML (C#)](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/HTML%20(C%23)) via Package Control, that extends HTML highlighting for C#-specific tags and logic blocks.

**Historic Answer**

1. Open any `.cshtml` file
2. In the main-menu, choose `View > Syntax > Open all with current extension as…` and select HTML

Comment: Why couldn't I find any tutorial online that just said that?? They all wanted me to open my HTML.sublime-settings. Thanks!

Comment: Well this is only applying HTML formatting - none of the Razor syntax is highlighted - so it's at best a 50% solution.

Comment: Hey, you [stole (link to revision)](https://superuser.com/revisions/1198446/2) my [answer (below)](https://superuser.com/a/1656900/114388). Hope you at least upvoted me. ;^D

Answer (score 1):

You can also install syntax packages with [Sublime Package Control](https://packagecontrol.io/).

For cshtml/aspx/etc, one option is [HTML (C#)](https://github.com/michaelblyons/SublimeSyntax-HTML-CSharp).

In Windows, if package control is installed

- Ctrl-shift-p
- Type "Install Package" (exclusive of quotes)
- Select Package Control: Install Package
- Type "html c#"
- Select extension pictured below to install.
- Close and reopen files

[image: Picture of HTML (C#) package in sublime]

**NOTE:** This also addresses [Nico's comment](https://superuser.com/questions/1198407/how-to-get-sublime-text-3-to-automatically-highlight-cshtml-as-html/1656900#comment2042465_1198446) that mapping to an existing package only highlights html ("a 50% solution") by syntax highlighting the Razor/C# code as well (a 99.44% solution!).